# Show u8 slice in hex representation

Tags: hex, rust, slice

I need to convert `&[u8]` to a hex representation. For example `[ A9, 45, FF, 00 ... ]`.

The trait `std::fmt::UpperHex` is not implemented for slices (so I can't use `std::fmt::format`). Rust has the `serialize::hex::ToHex` trait, which converts `&[u8]` to a hex String, but I need a representation with separate bytes.

I can implement trait `UpperHex` for `&[u8]` myself, but I'm not sure how canonical this would be. What is the most canonical way to do this?

Comment: When you say a "hex representation", do you mean you want a string in the end? Or what type?

Comment: BTW, you can't implement `UpperHex` for `&[u8]`, because both the trait and the type are not "yours" (neither of them is defined in your crate). You can implement `UpperHex` for a newtype for `&[u8]` (e.g. `struct HexSlice<'a>(&'a [u8])`, but it will likely be inconvenient. Defining a simple function is better.

Comment: Vladimir Matveev, I meant create new type, wich contains [u8] and use it. Thx for answer.

Comment: I can't find the serialize namespace. Is that from an external crate? In serialize::hex::ToHex. How do I use it? `use serialize;` just yields a compile error.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

## Rust 1.26.0 and up

The `:x?` "debug with hexadecimal integers" formatter can be used:

```
let data = b"hello";
// lower case
println!("{:x?}", data);
// upper case
println!("{:X?}", data);

let data = [0x0, 0x1, 0xe, 0xf, 0xff];
// print the leading zero
println!("{:02X?}", data);
// It can be combined with the pretty modifier as well
println!("{:#04X?}", data);
```

Output:

```
[68, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f]
[68, 65, 6C, 6C, 6F]
[00, 01, 0E, 0F, FF]
[
    0x00,
    0x01,
    0x0E,
    0x0F,
    0xFF,
]
```

If you need more control or need to support older versions of Rust, keep reading.

## Rust 1.0 and up

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    for &byte in "Hello".as_bytes() {
        write!(&mut s, "{:X} ", byte).expect("Unable to write");
    }

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

This can be fancied up by implementing one of the formatting traits ([`fmt::Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/macro.Debug.html), [`fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html), [`fmt::LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html), [`fmt::UpperHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.UpperHex.html), etc.) on a wrapper struct and having a little constructor:

```
use std::fmt;

struct HexSlice<'a>(&'a [u8]);

impl<'a> HexSlice<'a> {
    fn new<T>(data: &'a T) -> HexSlice<'a>
    where
        T: ?Sized + AsRef<[u8]> + 'a,
    {
        HexSlice(data.as_ref())
    }
}

// You can choose to implement multiple traits, like Lower and UpperHex
impl fmt::Display for HexSlice<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        for byte in self.0 {
            // Decide if you want to pad the value or have spaces inbetween, etc.
            write!(f, "{:X} ", byte)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    // To get a `String`
    let s = format!("{}", HexSlice::new("Hello"));

    // Or print it directly
    println!("{}", HexSlice::new("world"));

    // Works with
    HexSlice::new("Hello"); // string slices (&str)
    HexSlice::new(b"Hello"); // byte slices (&[u8])
    HexSlice::new(&"World".to_string()); // References to String
    HexSlice::new(&vec![0x00, 0x01]); // References to Vec<u8>
}
```

You can be even fancier and create an *extension trait*:

```
trait HexDisplayExt {
    fn hex_display(&self) -> HexSlice<'_>;
}

impl<T> HexDisplayExt for T
where
    T: ?Sized + AsRef<[u8]>,
{
    fn hex_display(&self) -> HexSlice<'_> {
        HexSlice::new(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", "world".hex_display());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the format string be `"{:02X}"` to ensure that two hex characters are printed for each character (including the first `0` if needed)?

Comment: @phoenix yep, if that's what is needed. That's what I mean by the comment "Decide if you want to pad out the value here".

Comment: You need `"{:02x?}"`. It still prints it as a comma separated list though. :-/

Comment: Yes, reminder to people you need to zero pad with `{:02X?}` if you're going to pasting the resulting string to a hex editor etc. Just wasted a bunch of time figuring out why I got garbage values.

Answer (score 21):

Use `hex::encode` from the [hex](https://crates.io/crates/hex) crate.

```rust
let a: [u8;4] = [1, 3, 3, 7];
assert_eq!(hex::encode(&a), "01030307");
```

```ini
[dependencies]
hex = "0.4"
```

Answer (score 11):

Since the accepted answer doesn't work on Rust 1.0 stable, here's my attempt. Should be allocationless and thus reasonably fast. This is basically a formatter for [u8], but because of the coherence rules, we must wrap `[u8]` to a self-defined type `ByteBuf(&[u8])` to use it:

```
struct ByteBuf<'a>(&'a [u8]);

impl<'a> std::fmt::LowerHex for ByteBuf<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, fmtr: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        for byte in self.0 {
            fmtr.write_fmt(format_args!("{:02x}", byte))?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let buff = [0_u8; 24];
println!("{:x}", ByteBuf(&buff));
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm doing it this way:

```
let bytes : Vec<u8> = "привет".to_string().as_bytes().to_vec();
let hex : String = bytes.iter()
  .map(|b| format!("{:02x}", b).to_string())
  .collect::<Vec<String>>()
  .join(" ");
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this snippet could be simplified to: `let bytes = "hello".to_string().into_bytes();` and `let hex = bytes.iter().map(|b| format!("{:02x}", b)).collect::<Vec<_>>().join(" ");`

Comment: No need to join. Just collect it as String

Comment: Without the join there will be no spaces between the hex characters.

Answer (score 6):

There's a crate for this: [hex-slice](https://docs.rs/hex-slice/*/hex_slice/).

For example:

```
extern crate hex_slice;
use hex_slice::AsHex;

fn main() {
    let foo = vec![0u32, 1, 2 ,3];
    println!("{:02x}", foo.as_hex());
}
```

Comment: Underrated comment!  Thanks, there's also the https://docs.rs/bytes/1.4.0/bytes/struct.Bytes.html which implements LowerHex but hex-slice is much more lightweight.