# How do I print a vector of u8 as a string?

Tags: rust

Here's my code:

```
let mut altbuf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

// Stuff here...

match stream.read_byte() {
    Ok(d) => altbuf.push(d),
    Err(e) => { println!("Error: {}", e); doneflag = true; }
}

for x in altbuf.iter() {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

The code prints u8 bytes which are correct, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to convert a vector of pure u8 bytes into a string? The only other answer to a similar question on stack overflow assumes that you're working with a vector of type &[u8].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the spirit of asking great questions, you may want to reword your question a bit. Your title makes it sound like you just want to [print the vector of bytes](http://is.gd/1kODTT), which is fairly easy. Your body makes it seem like you want to treat a sequence of bytes as a UTF-8 string, but you don't mention what encoding the bytes are in. You may also want to include some detail about what you are trying to do; perhaps a solution like [`read_to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html#method.read_to_string) would solve your real problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at the [`String` documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html), there are a few methods you could use.  There's [`String::from_utf8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) that takes a `Vec<u8>`, and there's also [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) which takes a `&[u8]`.

Note that a `Vec<T>` is more-or-less an owned, resizable wrapper around a `[T]`.  That is, if you have a `Vec<u8>`, you can turn it into a `&[u8]`, most easily by re-borrowing it (*i.e.* `&*some_vec`).  You can also call any methods defined on `&[T]` directly on a `Vec<T>` (in general, this is true of things that implement the [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait).

Comment: Hi DK, could you please link me to a resource clarifying re-borrowing? To expand further, when I try to do println!("{}", &*altbuf); I get "trait core::fmt::String is not implemented for type [u8]".

Comment: @AAnderson: You probably want `println!("{:?}", &*altbuf)`.  `{}` uses the `String` formatter which is for user-facing display, whilst `{:?}` is for just any sort of internal representation.  Not everything *has* a `String` formatter, but almost everything has a `Show` formatter (which is what `{:?}` uses).  To clarify re-borrowing: it's basically just calling `Deref::deref` on a thing and preserving the reference it returns (normally, the result of a `deref` call is automatically de-referenced; the extra `&` prevents that).  I don't know of any more explicit explanation anywhere.

Comment: For printing, creating a `String` object is not necessary. `std::str::from_utf8` is enough. I left another answer including example code.

Answer (score 6):

If your `altbuf` is a vector of `u8` as shown, this should work:

```
println!("{:?}", altbuf);
```

Here is an edited piece of code I have that does something similar:

```
let rebuilt: Vec<u8>;

unsafe {
    ret = proc_pidpath(pid, buffer_ptr, buffer_size);
    rebuilt = Vec::from_raw_parts(buffer_ptr as *mut u8, ret as usize, buffer_size as usize);
};

println!("Returned a {} byte string", ret);
println!("{:?}", rebuilt);
```

That rebuilds a vector of `u8` values from a buffer filled by a C function called via FFI so the bytes could be anything, maybe not valid UTF-8.

When I run it, the output is:

> Returned a 49 byte string
>
> [47, 85, 115, 101, 114, 115, 47, 97, 110,
>   100, 114, 101, 119, 47, 46, 114, 98, 101, 110, 118, 47, 118, 101, 114,
>   115, 105, 111, 110, 115, 47, 49, 46, 57, 46, 51, 45, 112, 51, 57, 50,
>   47, 98, 105, 110, 47, 114, 117, 98, 121]

You could format the numbers printed (in hex, octal, etc) using [different format strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits) inside the `{}`.

You can get a `String` from that using `String::from_utf8(rebuilt)` - which may return an error.

```
match String::from_utf8(rebuilt) {
    Ok(path) => Ok(path),
    Err(e) => Err(format!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e)),
}
```

Comment: [Using a byte literal](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=f270884d23f154f96e98e2deaca6625b) would probably be a clearer example than using FFI and `unsafe`. Could you show an example of printing the entire slice as hex numbers? I [don't believe that works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27650312/155423), but would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I think that's enough, and printing is different formats can be an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

To print bytes as a UTF-8 string, use [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) when the bytes may be malformed. Use the unsafe [`std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html) when the bytes are always valid UTF-8.

```rust
println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&altbuf).unwrap());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `write` method from `std::io`:

```rust
use std::{io, io::Write};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
   io::stdout().write(b"March\n")?;
   Ok(())
}
```

It prints a slice of `u8`, also known as a bytestring.

[`io::stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.stdout.html)