# Manipulate Result type with JSON as content

Tags: api, rust, twitch

This is a follow-up on the question [Why do I get a list of numbers instead of JSON when using the Twitch API via Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279141/why-do-i-get-a-list-of-numbers-instead-of-json-when-using-the-twitch-api-via-rus?noredirect=1#comment56300639_34279141) If I use the solution suggested in the previous post:

> Use the `response.get_body()` method to get a list of byte number which can be converted to a `Result` with `from_utf8()` method.

This returns a `Result` with everything in it. I'm not sure how to manipulate it. I was hoping I could use it like an array but the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) and [rustbyexample](http://rustbyexample.com/std/result.html) don't seem to explain it. What is the purpose of a `Result` type?

[This is the exact response](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/adrianz/Gddeb) that I'm getting from the body after converting it to UTF-8.

Comment: Please take some time to create high-value questions. It is expected that you ask [a single question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829) that [has effort put into it to make it good](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide a title that *indicates your question*. Use tags that help refine your question - why is this tagged `c++` if the question has *nothing* to do with C++? Asking if you should use a library is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't want to follow SO rules, the [Rust User forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) may be more suitable.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, the title is vague. In the body of the question, I'm uncertain about my own approach and ask if I should change my approach by changing the crate or if I should continue. The question is tagged with c++ because stackoverflow tag suggestion recommended that. The question was apparently clear enough because Robin Krahl answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Result` type does not help you here – it just stores arbitrary data and is used for error handling (instead of exceptions). But you can use the [`rustc_serialize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/index.html) crate to parse the string returned by the `Result`:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {
    let response_result = /* ... */;
    let data = response_result.unwrap();
    let json = Json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json.find("status").unwrap());
}
```

Comment: That's probably the reason why I could not find how to manipulate it. I was just assuming that I could. If I try your code sample I receive an error about that Json type does not implement the 'get' method.

Comment: @AdrianZ. I’m sorry, it should be `find`. I’ll correct it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Do you know any other crates that could potentially help with this project?