# How do I convert Base58-encoded data to a Vec<u8> and then into a String?

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a `Vec` to a `String` for display. I have tried to use `from_uf8` and `from_iter` with no luck.

```
use rust_base58::{ToBase58, FromBase58};

let address = String::from("1BgGZ9tcN4rm9KBzDn7KprQz87SZ26SAMH");
let _hash160 = address.from_base58();
let mut s = String::from_utf8(_hash160).unwrap();
//let s = String::from_iter(_hash160);
s.remove(0);
s.pop();
s.pop();
s.pop();
s.pop();
println!("{}", s);
```

Comment: Best to include the full error message you're getting along with the code.

Comment: Do *not* use variables that you've prepended with an underscore. A leading underscore means that the variable is deliberately **unused**.

Answer (score 2):

```
.from_base58()
```

returns

```
Result<Vec<u8>, FromBase58Error>
```

because the conversion can fail if the data isn't valid Base 58.

Assuming you want to ignore the error like you did for `from_utf8`, you'll need to `.unwrap()` that to get the `Vec<u8>` that you are looking for, e.g.

```
let hash160 = address.from_base58().unwrap();
let mut s = String::from_utf8(hash160).unwrap();
```

and the rest should compile fine, following the instructions laid out in [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076719/155423).

When you're making the code production-ready, definitely make sure to handle the errors without `.unwrap()` though.

Comment: yep I did not unwarp

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to unwrap, you can also handle the error.

Comment: @mcarton True, added a note. I was just assuming that error handling wasn't critical yet since the `from_utf8` was also unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you part of the problem.

```
 --> src/main.rs:7:35
  |
7 |     let mut s = String::from_utf8(_hash160).unwrap();
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found enum `std::result::Result`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<_>`
             found type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<_>, rust_base58::base58::FromBase58Error>`
  = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
          - .unwrap()
          - .unwrap_or_default()
```

You're trying to use `_hash160` as a `Vec<u8>`. But `from_base58` returns a `Result<Vec<u8>, FromBase58Error>`. You have to deal with that `Result`. A full program would have error handling, but for now we can use `unwrap` which will error if the `_hash160` is an error.

```
let _hash160 = address.from_base58().unwrap();
```

`_hash160` is fine, but we get an error from `String::from_utf8(_hash160).unwrap();`.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: FromUtf8Error { bytes: [0, 117, 30, 118, 232, 25, 145, 150, 212, 84, 148, 28, 69, 209, 179, 163, 35, 241, 67, 59, 214, 81, 13, 22, 52], error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 4, error_len: Some(1) } }'
```

[`Utf8Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/str/struct.Utf8Error.html) tells us that the 5th byte is invalid. The sequence of bytes in hash160 is not a valid UTF8 string.

If we try `String::from_utf8_lossy`...

```
println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&_hash160));
```

...we get a bunch of nonsense.

```
4v����T�Eѳ�#�C;�Q
```

It's not a valid [ASCII string](http://www.asciitable.com/) either, 232 is too high. We can check this explicitly with [`std::ascii::AsciiExt::is_ascii`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html#tymethod.is_ascii).

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;

...

# false
println!("{}", _hash160.is_ascii());
```

You'll likely just have to treat this as a sequence of bytes. You can print it in debug mode.

```
println!("{:?}", _hash160);
```

Which gives:

```
[0, 117, 30, 118, 232, 25, 145, 150, 212, 84, 148, 28, 69, 209, 179, 163, 35, 241, 67, 59, 214, 81, 13, 22, 52]
```

Comment: Nice breakdown.  Looks like I will have to convert each byte to a char for display then.

Comment: @user3266287 You can't, they're not even valid as single-byte UTF-8. For example 232 is `e8` which is not [valid UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). I suspect the original data is just a string of bytes. [Display them as hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650312/show-u8-slice-in-hex-representation#27650405).

Comment: for x in &_hash160 {
        print!("{:x}", x);
    }