# Can I format debug output as binary when the values are in a vector?

Tags: rust

In Rust you can format numbers in different bases, which is really useful for bit twiddling:

```
println!("{:?} {:b} {:x}", 42, 42, 42); // 42 101010 2a
```

Ideally this would also work for vectors! While it works for hex:

```
println!("{:#x?}", vec![42, 43, 44]); // [ 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c ]
```

It does not work for binary:

```
println!("{:b}", vec![42, 43, 44]); // I wish this were [101010, 101011, 101100]
```

Instead giving:

> the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>: std::fmt::Binary` is not satisfied

Is there a way of doing binary formatting inside vectors?

Comment: I think your question is answered by [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650312/show-u8-slice-in-hex-representation). Please let us know whether this indeed answers your question, then we can mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show u8 slice in hex representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650312/show-u8-slice-in-hex-representation)

Comment: How is the "binary" part of the question answered by this other QA ?

Comment: That's awesome it works for hex! Unfortunately that doesn't work for binary output, which is where I'm at right now

Comment: I updated the question to get rid of hex references, so it's clearer it cares about binary (I originally didn't realise you could do any, so I was trying to be more general. My mistake!)

Comment: OP, is there a problem with the answer ? Why didn't you accept it?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I was waiting to see if there was an answer that wasn't writing custom code to do it, which is IMO the defacto non-answer to any of these library-style questions. It's been sitting around for awhile though, so it's the best answer, at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a direct way, no, but I would do something like this:

```
use std::fmt;

struct V(Vec<u32>);

// custom output
impl fmt::Binary for V {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        // extract the value using tuple idexing
        // and create reference to 'vec'
        let vec = &self.0;

        // @count -> the index of the value,
        // @n     -> the value
        for (count, n) in vec.iter().enumerate() { 
            if count != 0 { write!(f, " ")?; }

            write!(f, "{:b}", n)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("v = {:b} ", V( vec![42, 43, 44] ));
}
```

Output:

```
$ rustc v.rs && ./v
v = 101010 101011 101100
```

I'm using `rustc 1.31.1 (b6c32da9b 2018-12-18)`

Rust [fmt::binary](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Binary.html) reference.

Rust [fmt::Display](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.31.0/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_display.html) reference.

Comment: The intermediate `String` is [not needed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a4e46f4b81325d268629a112075ebda8).